# Как сделать выборку логина и пароля из БД и сверить со входными значениями?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

Как вытянуть из БД логин и пароль и сравнить их со входными данными которые были введены в `textbox`

```
  using (ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext(options))
        {
            var loginDates = db.Users.FromSqlRaw("SELECT Email, Password FROM Users").ToList();

            if(loginDates.Contains())
            {

            }

        }
```

Если брать этот код, то нужна перегрузка в виде `User item`, пытался перегрузить параметром `new User(_email, password)`, но объект entity не содержит в себе конструктора с принимаемыми параметры, то есть была идея передать логин и дату через переменные и сравнить с данными из БД.

Содержание User

```
class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(24)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(24)]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(24)]
    public string Town { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(24)]
    public string Street { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(24)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: *Как вытянуть из БД логин и пароль и сравнить их со входными данными которые были введены в textbox* Добавьте в запрос WHERE clause с введёнными значениями, и смотрите, нулевое количество записей вернётся или нет.

Comment: @Akina то есть смысла в `if(loginDates.Contains())` и в  `var loginDates = db.Users.FromSqlRaw("SELECT Email, Password FROM Users").ToList();` нет? Просто вызвать метод в `if()` `db.Users.FromSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE email=" + emailBox.Text + " AND password=" + passwordBox.Text;")`  и сделать проверку на null?

Comment: Ну вот какой смысл волочь ВСЮ таблицу на клиента и там трахаться со сравнением? *Просто вызвать метод ... и сделать проверку на null?* Не. Сделать `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...` и проверить, ноль или не очень.

Comment: @Akina спасибо, просто не давно начал с SQL знакомиться и не знаю всех особенностей)